# background square with one side at an angle

Tags: css, background-image, transparent, css-shapes

I want to be able to create a transparent background using only CSS but with an angle on one end. I've found various ways of trying to do it, but can't quite get it. I don't really want to use any scripting, just CSS.

Background image would need to look like this:

[image: square with slanted side]

Comment: Here are various examples: http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could do it using borders: http://jsfiddle.net/wNhjb/

```
#shape {
   height: 0; 
   width: 80px;
   border-top: 80px solid blue;
   border-left: 40px solid transparent;
}
```

​

Comment: @Alex do you happen to know how cross browser this is? Does IE render it the same way?

Comment: @ns47731 I never tested it, but this should be the behavior defined in the standards. So it *should* look the same in every more or less standard-compliant browser.